# serialversionuid is static and final but then why is it serializable

Tags: java, serialization

As we know static fields are not serializable.

But the `serialversionUID` in our class is final and static. How is it serialized even if it is static and final?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the serialization process, one of the things that gets written is the class descriptor. This class descriptor contains the name and the serialVersionUID of the class.

The method can be found in the class java.io.ObjectStreamClass(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.html)

```
/**
 * Writes non-proxy class descriptor information to given output stream.
 */
void writeNonProxy(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeUTF(name);
    out.writeLong(getSerialVersionUID());

    byte flags = 0;
    if (externalizable) {
        flags |= ObjectStreamConstants.SC_EXTERNALIZABLE;
        int protocol = out.getProtocolVersion();
        if (protocol != ObjectStreamConstants.PROTOCOL_VERSION_1) {
            flags |= ObjectStreamConstants.SC_BLOCK_DATA;
        }
    } else if (serializable) {
        flags |= ObjectStreamConstants.SC_SERIALIZABLE;
    }
    if (hasWriteObjectData) {
        flags |= ObjectStreamConstants.SC_WRITE_METHOD;
    }
    if (isEnum) {
        flags |= ObjectStreamConstants.SC_ENUM;
    }
    out.writeByte(flags);

    out.writeShort(fields.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        ObjectStreamField f = fields[i];
        out.writeByte(f.getTypeCode());
         out.writeUTF(f.getName());
        if (!f.isPrimitive()) {
            out.writeTypeString(f.getTypeString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't serialised in the way you mean. It is transmitted as part of the class information the first time an instance of the class is serialized. It isn't the same thing.

Comment: I would like to know more about this. can you please provide references?

Comment: See the [Object Serialization Specification, Protocol Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

Answer (score 0):

`serialVersionUID` is a static field and isn't transmitted with the object. But `serialVersionUID` is transmitted with the class, and that class is subject to the handle mechanism, which means it is only transmitted once per stream.

Comment: You can't cite non-normative references. That's just another web page, with if anything somewhat less authority than this one. It is quite clear from the Object Serialiation Specification that the serialVersionUID isn't transmitted with the object at all, but with the *class,* and that the class is subject to the handle mechanism, which means it is only transmitted once per stream.

Comment: @EJP I agree using unoffical java references is not a good idea. I found the information mentioned there is correct so mentioned it for further reading.

Comment: It is not correct. Even if it was, it is still a non-normative reference, and should not be cited.

Comment: Now you've removed the citation but not the error you copied from it. Your answer remains incorrect.

Comment: And more than 50% of it now consists of unacknowledged plagiarism from my answer and comments.

Comment: @EJP yeah i tried to follow ur comments and incorporated them in my answer. Thanks!